# Undo records modified using gridview if user clicks Cancel

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I've got a user modification page, that displays a list of reports a user has access to using a GridView object.

What I want to do is, if someone makes a bunch of changes to a users page, but then clicks cancel, all changes that are made will be undone.
My main issue here is the GridView, which has add/delete/modify buttons, tied to a separate table.

So if I open my own page, add a new report to the gridview, then hit cancel, I don't want that report to be saved to my account.. 
Likewise, if I delete a record, and then hit cancel, the record is not deleted.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you using WinForm or WebForm? If it is webform and you are using DataSet, you can rebind your grid using a view filtered by RowState filter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain this in the `datatable` and put this in a `Session` variable and bind your gridview to your datatable that is in the session. So once you are finished with the changes and want to submit the changes in the DB, you have to `play with Datatable Row State`, from which you can find which row is added and which one is Deleted or Modified.

Have a look at this article to understand Datatable Row state
[system.data.datarow.rowstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In such case you mustn't bind GridView to the real datasource (Entity framework). If you do it changes will be written to the database and you will have very hard time to roll them back. GridView must work with temporary data stored for example in the session and only after commiting changes (Save button on the page) the data will be written to the database by EF.